Livewire 3: Uncaught Snapshot missing on Livewire component with id:
MyAd.php
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Models\Estate;
use Auth;
use Livewire\Component;

class MyAd extends Component
{
    public $active = [];
    public $fail = [];
    public $archive = [];
    public $note = [];
    public $moderation = [];
    public $user_id;
    public $search;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->user_id = Auth::guard('web')->id();
        $this->listAd();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.my-ad');
    }

    private function listAd(): void
    {
        if ($this->search != '') {
            $estates = Estate::where('user_id', $this->user_id)->where('id', 'like', $this->search)->orderBy('id', 'desc');
        } else {
            $estates = Estate::where('user_id', $this->user_id)->orderBy('id', 'desc');
        }
        $this->active = (clone $estates)->where('status', Estate::STATUS_ACTIVE)->get();
        $this->fail = (clone $estates)->where('status', Estate::STATUS_FAIL)->get();
        $this->archive = (clone $estates)->where('status', Estate::STATUS_ARCHIVE)->get();
        $this->note = (clone $estates)->where('status', Estate::STATUS_NOTE)->get();
        $this->moderation = (clone $estates)->whereIn('status', [Estate::STATUS_NEW, Estate::STATUS_UPDATE])->get();
    }

    public function searchAd()
    {
        $this->listAd();
    }
}

my-ad.blade.php
@php
    $activeTab = '#adv1';
    if (count($active) > 0 && count($note) == 0 && count($moderation) == 0) {
        $activeTab = '#adv1';
    } else if (count($moderation) > 0) {
        $activeTab = '#adv5';
    } else if (count($active) == 0 && count($note) > 0 && count($moderation) == 0) {
        $activeTab = '#adv4';
    } else if (count($active) == 0 && count($note) == 0 && count($moderation) == 0 && count($fail) == 0) {
        $activeTab = '#adv1';
    } else if (count($active) == 0 && count($note) == 0 && count($moderation) == 0 && count($fail) > 0) {
        $activeTab = '#adv2';
    } else if (count($active) == 0 && count($note) == 0 && count($moderation) == 0 && count($fail) == 0 && count($archive) > 0) {
        $activeTab = '#adv3';
    }
@endphp
<div class="right-board">
    <div class="caption-h-btn mobile-wrap">
        <h1>@lang('app.Мои объявления')</h1>
        <div class="small-search-field">
            <i class="ico-search"></i>
            <input type="text" wire:model="search" wire:keydown.enter="searchAd()"
                   placeholder="@lang('app.Поиск объявлений')">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-wrapper">
        <div class="overflow-scroll-box">
            <ul class="head-tab like-button2 white-space-nowrap">
                <li><a href="#adv1"
                       @if ($activeTab == '#adv1') class="active" @endif>@lang('app.Активные') {{count($active)}}</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#adv2"
                       @if ($activeTab == '#adv2') class="active" @endif>@lang('app.Отклоненные') {{count($fail)}}</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#adv3"
                       @if ($activeTab == '#adv3') class="active" @endif>@lang('app.Архив') {{count($archive)}}</a></li>
                <li><a href="#adv4"
                       @if ($activeTab == '#adv4') class="active" @endif>@lang('app.Черновики') {{count($note)}}</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#adv5"
                       @if ($activeTab == '#adv5') class="active" @endif>@lang('app.На модерации') {{count($moderation)}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="body-tab {{$activeTab == '#adv1' ? 'active' : ''}}" id="adv1">
            @foreach($active as $item)
                <div class="box-board-border">
                    @include('inc.ad_profile', ['item' => $item])
                </div>
            @endforeach
            @if (count($active) == 0)
                <p class="clean-tab-text">@lang('app.У вас нет добавленных объявлений')</p>
            @endif
        </div>
        <div class="body-tab {{$activeTab == '#adv2' ? 'active' : ''}}" id="adv2">
            @foreach ($fail as $item)
                <div class="box-board-border">
                    @include('inc.ad_profile', ['item' => $item])
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        <div class="body-tab {{$activeTab == '#adv3' ? 'active' : ''}}" id="adv3">
            @foreach ($archive as $item)
                <div class="box-board-border" wire:id="my-ad-{{$item->id}}">
                    @include('inc.ad_profile', ['item' => $item])
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        <div class="body-tab {{$activeTab == '#adv4' ? 'active' : ''}}" id="adv4">
            @foreach ($note as $item)
                <div class="box-board-border">
                    @include('inc.ad_profile', ['item' => $item])
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        <div class="body-tab {{$activeTab == '#adv5' ? 'active' : ''}}" id="adv5">
            @foreach ($moderation as $item)
                <div class="box-board-border">
                    @include('inc.ad_profile', ['item' => $item])
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

ad-profile.blade.php
<div class="one-adv-board {{$item->status == \App\Models\Estate::STATUS_ARCHIVE ? 'old' : ''}}">
    @if($item->status == \App\Models\Estate::STATUS_ARCHIVE)
        <div class="status-board-adv">@lang('app.В архиве')</div>
    @endif
    <div class="top-part">
        <div class="box-img"><img src="{{$item->getCover()}}" alt="img"></div>
        <div class="description">
            <div class="des-number">
                <div class="price">{{$item->formatPrice()}}
                    <div class="old-price">{{$item->priceByMetr()}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="number-adv">@lang('app.Номер объявления:') {{$item->id}}</div>
            </div>
            <p>{{$item->title}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    @if ($item->status == \App\Models\Estate::STATUS_ACTIVE)
        <hr>
        <div class="statistic">
            <div class="one-stat">
                <div class="number">{{\App\Models\Analytic::getData([\App\Models\Analytic::TYPE_SHOW_IN_SEARCH, \App\Models\Analytic::TYPE_SHOW_IN_HOME, \App\Models\Analytic::TYPE_SHOW_IN_AD], $item->id)}}</div>
                @lang('app.Показов в поиске')
            </div>
            <div class="one-stat">
                <div class="number">{{\App\Models\Analytic::getData([\App\Models\Analytic::TYPE_VIEW], $item->id, [now()->modify("-30days")->format("Y-m-d"), now()->format("Y-m-d")])}}</div>
                @lang('app.Просмотр за месяц')
            </div>
            <div class="one-stat">
                <div class="number">{{\App\Models\Analytic::getData([\App\Models\Analytic::TYPE_SHOW_IN_SEARCH, \App\Models\Analytic::TYPE_SHOW_IN_HOME, \App\Models\Analytic::TYPE_SHOW_IN_AD], $item->id, [now()->format("Y-m-d"), now()->format("Y-m-d")])}}</div>
                @lang('app.Показов сегодня')
            </div>
            <div class="one-stat">
                <div class="number">{{\App\Models\Analytic::getData([\App\Models\Analytic::TYPE_ADD_TO_FAVORITE], $item->id)}}</div>
                @lang('app.Добавили в избранное')
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="list-buttons-board">
            <a href="#" class="active">@lang('app.Продать быстрее с риелтором')</a>
            <a href="#promoteAd-{{$item->id}}" class="btn-change-modal"><i
                        class="ico-trending-up"></i><span>@lang('app.Продвинуть')</span></a>
            <a href="{{\App\Models\Menu::makeLink('item', ['id' => $item->id])}}" target="_blank"><i
                        class="ico-external-link"></i><span>@lang('app.Открыть')</span></a>
            <a href="{{\App\Models\Menu::makeLink('ad-edit', ['id' => $item->id])}}"><i
                        class="ico-edit-3"></i><span>@lang('app.Редактировать')</span></a>
            <a href="#moveAnnouncement-{{$item->id}}" class="btn-change-modal"><i
                        class="ico-x-octagon"></i><span>@lang('app.Снять с публикации')</span></a>
        </div>
    @else
        @php
            switch ($item->status) {
                case \App\Models\Estate::STATUS_FAIL:
                    $buttons = [['icon' => 'ico-edit-3', 'title' => __('app.Редактировать'), 'link' => \App\Models\Menu::makeLink('ad-edit', ['id' => $item->id])], ['icon' => 'ico-trash-2', 'title' => __('app.Удалить'), 'prop' => 'wire:click.prevent=removeAd('.$item->id.') wire:confirm="'. __('app.Вы действительно хотите удалить объявление?').'"']];
                    if (!is_null($item->reject_reason)) {
                        $reason = \App\Models\EstateRejectReason::find($item->reject_reason);
                        $content = '<ul class="list-statuses">
                            <li class="status-search gray">'.$reason->t('text').'</li>
                        </ul>
                        <hr>';
                    } else {
                        $content = '<hr>';
                    }
                    break;

                case \App\Models\Estate::STATUS_ARCHIVE:
                    $buttons = [['icon' => 'ico-corner-up-left', 'title' => __('app.Восстановить'), 'prop' => 'wire:click.prevent=moveToActive('.$item->id.')', 'modal' => 'fromArchive'], ['icon' => 'ico-trash-2', 'title' => __('app.Удалить'), 'prop' => 'wire:click.prevent=removeAd('.$item->id.') wire:confirm="'. __('app.Вы действительно хотите удалить объявление?').'"']];
                    $content = '';
                    break;

                case \App\Models\Estate::STATUS_NOTE:
                    $prompt = __('app.Вы действительно хотите удалить объявление?');
                    $buttons = [
                        [
                            'icon' => 'ico-edit-3',
                            'title' => __('app.Редактировать'),
                            'link' => \App\Models\Menu::makeLink('ad-edit', ['id' => $item->id])
                        ],
                        [
                            'icon' => 'ico-trash-2',
                            'title' => __('app.Удалить'),
                            'prop' => 'wire:click.prevent=removeAd('.$item->id.') wire:confirm="'.$prompt.'"'
                        ]
                    ];
                    break;

                case \App\Models\Estate::STATUS_UPDATE:
                case \App\Models\Estate::STATUS_NEW:
                    $buttons = [
                        [
                            'icon' => 'ico-edit-3',
                            'title' => __('app.Редактировать'),
                            'link' => \App\Models\Menu::makeLink('ad-edit', ['id' => $item->id])
                        ],
                    ];
                    break;

                default:
                    $content = '';
                    $buttons = [];
                    break;
            }
        @endphp
        <hr>
        {!! $content ?? '' !!}
        <div class="list-buttons-board">
            @foreach($buttons as $button)
                @if (isset($button['modal']) && $button['modal'] == 'fromArchive' && $item->active_to < now()->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"))
                    <livewire:return-ad template="mini" wire:key="return-ad-{{$item->id}}" :estate_id="$item->id"/>
                @else
                    <a href="{!! $button['link'] ?? '' !!}" {!! $button['prop'] ?? '' !!}><i
                                class="{{$button['icon']}}"></i><span>{{$button['title']}}</span></a>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endif
    <div class="wrapper-custom-modal size3 without-scroll" id="promoteAd-{{$item->id}}">
        <livewire:service :estate_id="$item->id" wire:key="service-{{$item->id}}" view="service-big"/>
        <div class="close-modal-bg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-custom-modal size2" id="moveAnnouncement-{{$item->id}}">
        <div class="modal-custom">
            <div class="caption-modal">
                @lang('app.Перенести объявления в архив')
                <div class="close-btn-style close-btn-modal"><i class="ico-close-l"></i></div>
            </div>
            <div class="gray-style-1 mb-16">
                @lang('app.Объявления хранятся в архиве бесплатно. Все данные по нему будут сохранены и вы сможете опубликовать его повторно.')
            </div>
            <a href="#" wire:click.prevent="moveToArchive({{$item->id}})"
               class="btn-dark inline secondary">@lang('app.Перенести в архив')</a>
        </div>
        <div class="close-modal-bg"></div>
    </div>
</div>

when I enter the ad id and press enter, I get an error:
Uncaught Snapshot missing on Livewire component with id:

I noticed 2 points. The first - if you enter such an id that does not exist, then nothing is displayed (which is correct) and there is no error. the impression is that the error occurs because one element is missing.
The second point: if I deduce that
<div class="body-tab {{$activeTab == '#adv4' ? 'active' : ''}}" id="adv4">
            @foreach ($note as $item)
                <div class="box-board-border">
                    {{$item->id}}
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>

There is no mistake either. i tried adding wire:key, wire:id, :key - all the same

How are my-ad.blade.php and ad-profile.blade.php related? Are they both placed together in a main component or layout?

my-ad.blade.php is a component template. ad-profile.blade.php is a single ad template that is included in a loop in my-ad.blade.php

In the request you indicated ad-profile.blade.php while the file is ad_profile.blade.php so I didn't understand.
The ad_profile view is very complex so I can't test it, also I see that you include it instead of using it as a component, which suggests that the system was written for Livewire 2.

With Livewire 3 try making these changes: when you use a child component, if needed, instead of wire:key="'prefix-{{ $variable }}" you must use :key="'prefix-' . $variable". Instead, since ad_profile is included into loops , try putting in the main  an attribute  wire:key="{{ $item->status . '-' . $item->id }}", or use another unique value in the page

in the loop I wrote like this @foreach($active as $item)@include('inc.ad_profile', ['item' => $item])@endforeach. the problem remained

"With Livewire 3 try making these changes: when you use a child component, if needed, instead of wire:key="'prefix-{{ $variable }}" you must use :key="'prefix-' . $variable"." - I'm not quite sure where I should add this?

@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')



@include('inc.my_left_sidebar', ['active' => 'grid'])
<livewire:my-ad :key="'my-ad'" />



@endsection - here?

Putting wire:key in the outer  before @include as you did seems correct.
:key="'prefix-' . $variable" must be set when using child components, for example *<livewire:return-ad template ..... /> (instead of wire:key="....."). Also make sure that 'prefix-' . $variable is a unique value

I solved the problem when I rewrote the code like this @foreach ($note as $item <div class="box-board-border"><livewire:ad-profile :key="'ad-profile-'.$item->id.'-tab4'" :item="$item"/></div>@endforeach. thanks @TUPKAP
